# Can you nest queries in Datadog?

Tags: datadog

I'd like to be able to nest one query within another in Datadog. For example, if I have a log of web requests and each request has a `x_session_id` I'd like to be able to search for a specific set of logs, perhaps `env:prod service:foo status:error`, then grab the `x_session_id` for each returned item and use that to then pull up all logs for all logs that contain those specific ids, grouping by id (I know how to do the group by ID).

I currently am doing this manually and slowly, searching for each id one by one in a separate tab. I'm trying to determine why a specific error is occurring and I'd like to see the entire timeline of events for each id together.